# Updating bash to 4.2 on OSX causes Terminal crash

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, updates, osx-yosemite

I updated to bash version 4.2.53 using this [site](http://techscienceinterest.blogspot.com/2010/05/change-to-new-bash-shell-41-for-mac-os.html). I'm running OSX 10.10.1 on my system. I am trying to do these last three steps:

10. Change to /bin by typing: cd /bin
11. Move bash to bash-old: sudo mv bash bash-old
12. Create a symlink to the new bash command: sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/bash bash

But when I try to cd into /bin the terminal crashes and quits. I tried to cd as root using sudo, but it will not go into the bin directory.

Comment: Try `sudo -i` and then executing the commands. I'm not familiar with OSX command line so it's just a guess. - Alternatively try to move the files without changing directory like this: `sudo mv /bin/bash /bin/bash-old`.

Comment: If all else fails, install bash from Homebrew. Google for recent [tutorials](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-homebrew-os-x-yosemite-10-10-package-manager-unix-apps/)...

Comment: Thanks ShellFish that worked!